# How to put a WinJs Pivot inside one of the pages of the split view

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, winjs, visual-studio-cordova

I am developing VS cordova app targeting for Microsoft surface and iOS platforms.

I have put a split view control in the index.html file and the corresponding js of it in index.js. In my split view I have 5 icons which navigate to various pages. The default page out of it has the pivot control which contains 8-10 pivot headers and their items we can swipe through.

Now when I package the app, all pages with all pivot elements show properly when I install it on my PC or view in the local device debug. But the same when I install on my Microsoft surface tab, the split view controls work fine, but the pivot control only shows the top 8-10 headers but not the elements under them like text boxes, list views and the rest. I am attaching a screenshot of the same for you to view.

**1st pic showing the screen in local device debugger**

[image]

**2nd pic showing how it comes in my Surface tab**

[image]

WHY IS THIS HAPPENING? PLEASE HELP!

One more important question is, As I am targeting my app for Windows and iOS . Will these WinJs controls work on an iOS device??
Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Sure I can. But please direct me how can I share it with you

Comment: You can share it through the online repository like [Github](https://github.com/) or [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-sg/) If you don't know how to use that, you can  Email me through xiaxucheng@gmail.com.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I've sent you a mail containing my project folder using Sendbigfiles.com. Please check it out and let me know why the above problems happen. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hello @ElvisXia-MSFT I request you to please have a look at it as soon as you are free and let me know what is going wrong in my project. I recently tested the same on my iPhone and the same problem exists. What is it so different in the Windows 8.1 to others that doesn't seem to load the screens properly.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I've checked the demo and reproduced the problem. The reason seems to be the pivot item. I'm currently looking into the reason. I'll let you know when I found out a solution.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT - Thank you so much! Will wait for your response.